# Group by weekday and ongoing in Solspace Calendar

Tags: plugin-solspacecalendar

I'm using the Craft `group` filter to group events by day:

```
{% set week = craft.calendar.events({
  dateRangeStart: 'today',
  dateRangeEnd: '3 days'
}) %}

{% set weekByDay = week|group('startDate|date("l")') %}

{% for day, eventsInDay in weekByDay %}

  <h1>{{ day }}</h1>

  {% for event in eventsInDay %}
    <h2>{{ event.title }}</h2>
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

How would I go about including events that are happening - but not necessarily starting - during each day?